# UWP/WinJS: show a html page in a pop-up window

Tags: win-universal-app, winjs

I am working on a JavaScript based UWP app. Now I need to dynamically show a html page(with a url) in a pop-up window. 
I did some search, there is a [ContentDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn904229.aspx) I can probably use:

```
var object = new WinJS.UI.ContentDialog(element, options);
```

but I cannot find any JavaScript sample code for it. I couldn't figure out what should I pass as "element" and how I put the html in ContentDialog. 
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WinJS playground shows you how to use the ContentDialog: http://winjs.azurewebsites.net/#contentdialog

The `element` you pass is the Html element you want to initiate as the dialog.

```
<div id="myDialog">I am the going to be the dialog content.</div>
```

```
var element = document.getElementById('myDialog');
var options = {
         title: 'Main instruction',
         primaryCommandText: 'Ok',
         secondaryCommandText: 'Cancel'
    };
var dialog = new WinJS.UI.ContentDialog(element, options);
```

If you want to set the dialog content dynamically you can do so with

```
var webview = document.createElement('x-ms-webview');
webview.src = 'http://stackoverflow.com';
dialog.element.querySelector('.win-contentdialog-content').appendChild(webview);
dialog.show();
```

Comment: Thanks Anthony, but you only answered half of my question. My purpose is to display a html page in ContentDialog, say an x-ms-webview inside ContentDialog. Using innerHTML doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: @user2643986 Sorry, missed that part about the webview. I edited my answer above.